# Is Senpou: Inton Raiha related to the Third Raikage's black lightning attack?

Tags: naruto

In chapter 674 of the Naruto manga, Madara uses a techinique called *Senpou: Inton Raiha*.
Is this technique related to the black lightning attack of the Third Raikage?

Answer (score 1):

[Senpou: Inton Raiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Art%3a_Yin_Release_Lightning_Dispatch) - Raiton and Inton mixed together to form a branched dangerous lightning network . The flashes can be fired from both hands simultaneously. Senpou: Inton Raiha uses Sage of Six Path's chakra. And till now there have been only 4 characters to use Sage of Six Path's chakra - Obito, Madara, Naruto and Sasuke. It is highly unlikely that Third raikage knew/believed in Rikudou Senin let alone had his chakra.

Also Third raikage's [black lightening](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Lightning) was unique to him and later used by Darui too and it is shown that it can be used at a single target at a time. It covers the whole body of the user while Senpou: Inton Raiha comes out from hands of user.

Answer (score 0):

From the Naruto wiki:

[Senpou: Inton Raiha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Art%3a_Yin_Release_Lightning_Dispatch) is a combination of senjutsu, Yin Release and Lightning Release.

[Black Lightning](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Lightning) is a typical lightning release jutsu.

Hence Inton Raiha and Black Lightning are not related to each other.